# Symfony2 always on Production enviroment with ngix + FastCGI PHP

Tags: symfony, nginx, environment-variables

I have my env with the following

- Windows 8
- Nginx 1.3.12
- PHP 5.3.3

Run php as CGI

```
php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Setup nginx

```
upstream phpfcgi {
    server  127.0.0.1:9000;
}    

server
{
    //...
    location / {
        index app_dev.php;
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app_dev.php/$1 last;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass phpfcgi;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS              off;
    }
}
```

I have the default app_dev.php for run the app into `dev` enviroment but always when i try `http://localhost/any/path` run into the `prod`, i know why this behavior. Even i've deleted the file `app.php`

```
#app_dev.php
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

// If you don't want to setup permissions the proper way, just uncomment the following PHP line
// read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup for more information
//umask(0000);

// This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1'))
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: Post the content of your app_dev.php

Comment: What's your ultimate goal? Do you want to access the dev site from that url? Or do you just want to access the dev site period?

Comment: I want access to the enviroment set in the file app_dev.php